# Запись в файл информации типа "Record"

Tags: delphi, файлы

Здравствуйте, подскажите, пожалуйста, как справится с такой проблемой: создал типизированный файл, имею определенную запись. Цель -  через консоль вписать определенную инфу. Выбивает ошибку еще на стадии компиляции, код прилагаю:

```
    type
      fullname = record
        surname:string[255];
        name:   string[255];
        midname:string[255];
      end;
    type
      fulldate = record
        day:  integer;
        month:integer;
        year: integer;
      end;
    type
      person = record
        fio:   fullname;
        adress:string[255];
        born:  fulldate;
        brain: double;
      end;
    type
    TArr = array of person;
    var
      f1:File of TArr;
      student : TArr;
      x:integer;
    //.....
    begin
  filename:=('H:\2 sem\progr\lab_works\Laba2\studMain.txt');
  AssignFile(f1,filename);
  Rewrite(f1);
  SetLength(stud,length(stud)+1);

  readln(stud[high(stud)].fio.surname);
  readln(stud[high(stud)].fio.name);
  readln(stud[high(stud)].fio.midname);
 readln(stud[high(stud)].adress);
 readDateBorn(student);
  readln(stud[high(stud)].brain);

  write(f1,stud);
  CloseFile(f1);
end;
//.......
Ошибка:Type 'TArr' needs finalization - not allowed in file type
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Файл не может быть типа динамического массива.

> To declare a file type, use the syntax
>
> type fileTypeName = file of type
>
> where fileTypeName is any valid identifier and type is a **fixed-size type**
>
> (c) Delphi help

Либо массив должен быть фиксированный:

```
TArr = array[1..10] of person;
```

либо в цикле пишите по одной структуре из массива:

```
f1: file of person;
...
write(f1,stud[i]);
```